# Show the number that appears the most times in a row

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, list

How to code a program that shows me the item that appears most **side-by-side**?

Example:

```
6 1 6 4 4 4 6 6
```

I want four, not six, because there are only two sixes together.

This is what I tried (from comments):

```
c = int(input())
h = [] 
for c in range(c):
    h.append(int(input()))
final = []
n = 0    
for x in range(c-1):
    c = x
    if h[x] == h[x+1]:
        n+=1
        while h[x] != h[c]:
            n+=1
        final.append([h[c],n])
print(final)
```

Comment: Can you please show what did you try as of now?

Comment: This : https://hastebin.com/gojegocobe.py

Comment: What do you mean "most side by side"? In a single batch? What is the "most side-by-side" in `1 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 1 1`?

Comment: @tobias_k The 4 2s surely

Comment: If you want something without any libraries, you can achieve this with a simple loop and some counting variables. Something along the lines of [this](https://ideone.com/Mfn82g). Probably just easier to use `groupby` or `Counter` as shown below.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what exactly you want for an input like

```
lst = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
```

If you consider the four `2` the most common, because it's the longest unbroken stretch of same items, then you can [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) same values and pick the one with `max` `len`:

```
max((len(list(g)), k) for k, g in itertools.groupby(lst))
# (4, 2)  # meaning 2 appeared 4 times
```

If you are interested in the element that appears the most often next to itself, you can `zip` the list to get pairs of adjacent items, filter those that are same, pass them through a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), and get the `most_common`:

```
collections.Counter((x,y) for (x,y) in zip(lst, lst[1:]) if x == y).most_common(1)
# [((1, 1), 4)]  # meaning (1,1) appeared 4 times
```

For your example of `6 1 6 4 4 4 6 6`, both will return `4`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 maxcount=0; //store maximum number item side by side
num=-1; //store element with max count 
 for i=0 to n //loop through your array
        count=0; 
        in=i;
        while(arr[in++]==arr[i]){//count number of side by side same element
           count++;
        }
        maxcount=max(maxcount,count);
        num= maxcount==count? arr[i]:num;
        i=in-1;
endfor;
```